# Automatic creation of the second WiFi interface with netplan (Ubuntu 20.04)

Tags: wireless-networking, systemd, wifi-configuration, ubuntu-20.04, netplan

I want to create wifi access point on my machine together with ordinary wifi interface. My card support this operation. I can do this manually with the following commands (note that wlan0 already exists and it is configured to connect to the office network)

```
iw phy phy0 interface add wlan1 type managed
service hostapd start
ip link set wlan1 up
ip addr add 10.0.10.1/24 dev wlan1
```

However, I want to create and this wlan1 interface automatically at the system startup. Previously (on Ubuntu 16.04) I did this with help of if-pre-up.d  script. However, netplan does not support pre-up scripts. As far as I understand I should either use `network-dispatcher` or create systemd unit that is run before starting network. What is the proper approach?
Are there good examples?

Answer (score 0):

This is the approach recommended by the [Netplan FAQ](https://netplan.io/faq/):

> Netplan configuration does not currently support hook scripts in its
> configuration definition.
>
> Instead to achieve this functionality with the networkd renderer users
> can use
> [networkd-dispatcher](https://gitlab.com/craftyguy/networkd-dispatcher).
> The package provides users and legacy packages hook points when
> specific network states are reached to aid in reacting to network
> state.

The FAQ gives an example of using networkd-dispatcher for running ifup hooks
via a script installed in `/etc/networkd-dispatcher/routable.d/50-ifup-hooks`,
where you may include your commands.
Note that such a script needs to be executable and owned by root.

Most sources I have seen recommended this approach as being the simplest.
In comparison, `systemd` is more complex and needs a steeper
learning curve.

Comment: The script that I need to port is in if-pre-up.d not in if-up.d. Nothing correspond to to if-pre-up.d in the given table. Also in the table we have configuring.d and configured.d listed, but there is no such directories in the actual installation of the networkd-dispatcher and I can not find any documentation on them.

Comment: I don't know about porting a script - the one that is in the post may work from inside `50-ifup-hooks`.

Comment: Well, as you may note the lines that are in the post _create_ interface wlan1. The script in routable.d run when the interface already exists. As far as I understand, networkd-dispatcher gets list of the existing interfaces from iw command, so it does not create any. I can, of course, create interface wlan1 when running script for wlan0, but it looks like an ugly hack.

Comment: Ugly hacks that work are not ugly.